# How to refresh data source on DevExtreme menu

Tags: angularjs, devextreme

I'm using `angular-translate` for i18n. Somewhat unfortunately, $translate service asynchronously loads strings.

I've copied in the relevant controller code. What is the best way to replace the current datasource items with a new array of items after the translations are loaded? (or after the user signs in this case). The code seems a bit clunky.

See below for my attempt.

```
var items = [
  {
    text: 'This option remains',
    uiState: 'signin',
    icon: 'user'
  }];

$scope.accountMenuDS = new DevExpress.data.DataSource({
  store: {
    type: "array",
    key: "text",
    data: items
  }
});

$translate(['users.signin']).then(function (trans) {
  if (!user) {

    var newItems = [
      {
        text: 'hello',
        uiState: 'signin',
        icon: 'key'
      }
    ];

    Array.prototype.splice.apply(items, [0, newItems.length].concat(newItems)); // is there a better way than this?

    $scope.accountMenuDS.reload();

  } else {
    // handle signed in case later
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you can use the [bindingOptions](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/16_2/Guide/Widgets/Common/Data_Visualization_Widgets/Charts_-_Data_Binding/Update_Data/#Using_AngularJS) field to provide two-way binding:

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div dx-menu="menuOptions"></div>
    <div dx-button="buttonOptions"></div>
</div>
```

Controller code:

```
myApp.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.menuData = [/*...*/];

    $scope.menuOptions = {
        bindingOptions: {
            dataSource: "menuData"
        }
    };

    $scope.buttonOptions = {
        text: "Update data",
        onClick: function() {
            $scope.menuData.push({
                text: "Item 3"
            });
        }
    };
});
```

See this [plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/FSHfgfSpiVQz6mSB9QaF?p=preview) as well.